# rails delayed_job not finding method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Using

```
delayed_job_active_record  4.1
rails 6.1.1
```

a method within a `cartitems` controller correctly calls and executes a method

```
set_qr_code(@cartitem.cart)
```

But being resource intensive, delayed_job should allow to complete the parent method and run the longer method on its own.  However, if the method is run with the delay verb

```
@cartitem.cart.delay.set_qr_code(@cartitem.cart)
```

The log show the complaint:

```
undefined method `set_qr_code' for #<Cart id: 64, ...
```

So although the method is cast in the `application_controller.rb` it is not being invoked.

The [documentation](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/tree/v4.1.11) has no explicit indications as to where such methods should be set.  Where should one define them?

Comment: The error is very clear. It is expecting the `set_qr_code` to be a method in the `Cart` model

Comment: cart 'model' or 'controller' (or both) ?

Answer (score 0):

@AbM is correct. You are calling the set_qr_code method on an instance of your Cart class so it needs to go in your Cart model, not the Carts Controller.

You can call `@cartitem.cart.delay.set_qr_code` without the @cartitem.cart argument from your controller action, then reference the instance as self in your model:

```
def set_qr_code
    self.do_something_here
end
```

The extra call to `set_qr_code(@cartitem.cart)` in your CartItems controller isn't strictly necessary unless you there are additional steps you want to perform there before triggering the delayed job call.